# Clion - cannot create a new rust file in the same project

Tags: rust, clion

I have just started learning rust. I'm using the CLion IDE and this is giving me some issues. Every time I try to create a new rust file I get a popup saying "File is not included in module tree, analysis is not available". This appears to be a known issue in CLion's rust plugin with the normal solution being to invalidate the cache and restart. However, I have tried that multiple times now and it still doesn't work. [image]

Does anyone know of a solution to this issue (or if I am doing something wrong)?

Comment: put your files in the src directory, then declare them with `mod file_name;` in main.rs. Consider `main.rs` the entry point of your program, the "module tree" start with it, then include whatever the file include.

Comment: @Bamontan is there not a way to create completely separate projects? I'm just trying out some programs while I work through my course so I'd rather not tie them all together.

Comment: Ho ok sorry I did'nt fully undertood your problem, as Kevin Reid said in his response you can have seperate crates in the bin folder, you can then do `cargo run --bin file_name` to run the one you want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

“File is not included in module tree” does not *just* mean that the IDE cannot analyze the file. It also means that the file won't be *compiled* (unless you use `rustc` manually, rather than `cargo build`).

In normal Rust development, every source file should belong to a [*Cargo package*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/appendix/glossary.html#package). If you want to keep them as simple as possible, the minimum contents of a package are

```rust
Cargo.toml
src/
    main.rs
```

(You do *not* need a separate version control repository for each package.)

If you have a large set of related programs, you can define them as multiple binary crates within a single package. They will share dependencies declared in one `Cargo.toml` (this does not increase the output code size) and build files (`target/`).

```rust
Cargo.toml
src/
    bin/
       prog1.rs
       prog2.rs
```

The `src/bin/` path [is where](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/guide/project-layout.html) Cargo automatically looks for files that are the crate roots (file that contains `fn main()`) for additional binaries beyond the default `src/main.rs`.

You *can* choose to develop programs as single files, without using Cargo, by running `rustc` on them directly. But it will be difficult to use any libraries (and using Rust without libraries at all is not usually a good plan), and your IDE will not be able to help you because IDEs get important context from Cargo.

Comment: If it does build, however, then it's a CLion / Rust plug-in bug. Happens to me every time I create a new file and/or folder. I don't usually need to invalidate the caches, though... just restarting the IDE is enough (as of October 20th, 2022).